# Problem setting up adminer with lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

How can I set up [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) with lighttpd? I installed Adminer from the repository with "sudo apt-get install adminer". And ran the following commands.

```
sudo wget "http://www.adminer.org/latest.php" -O /usr/share/adminer/latest.php
sudo ln -s /usr/share/adminer/latest.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php
echo "Alias /adminer.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php" > /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-adminer.conf
sudo service lighttpd restart
```

This is the symbolic links in conf-enabled.

```
$ ls -la conf-enabled
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 14 17:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr  4 11:34 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Apr 14 17:26 10-adminer.conf -> ../conf-available/10-adminer.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Apr  4 11:36 10-fastcgi.conf -> ../conf-available/10-fastcgi.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Apr  4 11:36 15-fastcgi-php.conf -> ../conf-available/15-fastcgi-php.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jan  1  1970 90-javascript-alias.conf -> ../conf-available/90-javascript-alias.conf
```

This is the content of 10-adminer.conf

```
$ cat conf-enabled/10-adminer.conf
Alias /adminer.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php
```

But when I restart lighttpd, I get the following error:

```
Job for lighttpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status lighttpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

'systemctrl status lighttpd.service' yields:

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-04-14 17:43:32 CEST; 36s ago
Process: 21057 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 31301 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -t -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
Main PID: 21057 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The prolem was that I was using Apache conf syntax instead of lighttpd conf syntax. I changed 10-adminer.conf as follows.

```
alias.url = ( "/adminer.php" => "/usr/share/adminer/adminer.php" )
```

It now works as expected.